# Joomla 3: How do I call an article from a menu item and show that menu as active?

Tags: joomla, menu

I have a standard navigation menu on my banner. Then I have another menu below that, in my body area, and this is used made to appear as 'tabs' by using css styling. Thus each tab (actually menu) has its own articles.

Now, When I click a tab, the article shows. But I have a link to the first tab on the top menu (in my banner). This links to the article in the first tab. When the menu item in the banner is clicked, the first tab's article shows fine. But it does not show the first tab as active. The first tab only shows as the active link when I click it.

How do I make the tab (menu item) active when the menu item in the banner is clicked?

To better illustrate this, I've included a screenshot.
[image]
Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing it this way instead of using a tab module which will provide Ajax tab change saving you a page load? Have you seen the flexibility in NoNumbers' Tabs?

Comment: As a new Joomla developer, I don't know much about the choices. But I thought that using tabs had no AJAX and that all tabs would be loaded and only one hidden. Furthermore, the method I've adopted would allow the user to easily add/remove more articles/tabs/menus with minimum effort on their part and mine. Hope I got this right :)

Comment: Fair enough, your way has an advantage in that you will be maitaining a one-2-one relationships between articles & urls..

Answer (score 1):

First you need to put both menus into one single menu since the second is basically a submenu of the first. 
After that is done you "split" the in two modules:
For the top menu you set the module options to "Start Level" 1 and "End Level" 1. And "Show Sub-menu Items" is set to "No".
The second module has the "Start Level" set to 2.

That should probably do what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs... I never knew this split option. Anyway I'm not an expert at this so I guess it should do the trick. But something I can do with my current method is to set the parent item of the menu using the Admin backend. And this is much easier from the level I reached thus far. Maybe I'm wrong but I just think this is possible. Thanks anyway.